# Insert into SQL Db from Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am looking to insert a python dataframe into MSSQL table using the below code:

```py
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};\
                       Server=esql.ecs.local;\
                       Database=drgt;\
                       Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()  #Create cursor


for row_count in range(0, t6.shape[0]):
    chunk = t6.iloc[row_count:row_count+1,:].values.tolist()
    tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in chunk)
    cursor.executemany("insert into DWWorking.dbo.api_Nic_Data"+"([[a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f],\
                                                      [g],[h],[i],[j],[k],[l],[m],[n],\
                                                      [o],[p],[q],[r],[s],[t],[u],[v],\
                                                      [w],[x],[y],[z],[ab],[cd],\
                                                      [ef],[gh],[ij],[kl]])\
                                                        values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                                                                    tuple_of_tuples)
```

The cursor is opened and I checked that the table exists and has the required columns.
I still receive the below error while executing:

> ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 33 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

How can I resolve?

Comment: Why not `df.to_sql()` using a `sqlalchemy` engine?  Surely more simple and likely more efficient. [pandas docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) and [sqlalchemy connstr docs here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc).

Comment: @S3DEV - Tried that as well using the below code:  t6.to_sql(api_nic_data,engine,index=False,if_exists="append",schema="dbo")
The error says name api_nic_data is not defined. This is the table name, and it definitely exists

Comment: Interesting. Even `'DWWorking.dbo.api_Nic_Data'`?  I’d keep trying with this, you’re on the right track.  TBH I’m not sure how much of the tablename pandas is looking for; (I avoid MSSQL at all cost). But again, you’re on the right track.

Comment: @S3DEV - turns out I was missing the single quotes  for the table name in my code above. That fixed the 1st error, but now I see:InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Comment: Glad that helped.  I’d recommend raising a new question, and provide the (sanitised) details of the connection string you’re using to create the sqlalchemy engine for `df.to_sql()`.

Comment: What is `DWWorking`? If that is the database, what is `drgt` in connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original query should work with proper SQL that does not have brackets enclosing the `INSERT INTO` column list. Additionally, `executemany` should not require any `for` loop across data frame rows and can be faster than `df.to_sql`. Also, table and column identifiers should not use single quotes.

By the way, for easier multi-line strings, consider Python's triple quote string. Do note, since Pandas v0.24, `.to_numpy` is recommended method over `.values` (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)). Below assumes data frame contains exactly 32 columns that each map to corresponding table column.

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO DWWorking.dbo.api_Nic_Data 
            ([a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f],[g],[h],[i],[j],
             [k],[l],[m],[n],[o],[p],[q],[r],[s],[t],
             [u],[v] [w],[x],[y],[z],[ab],[cd],[ef],[gh],[ij],[kl])
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                 ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                 ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
      """ 

cursor.executemany(sql, t6.to_numpy().tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide a proper answer for future readers ...

Following the comments, it would be more straight-forward and likely more efficient to use the following:

- pandas `DataFrame.to_sql()` function
- `sqlalchemy` `engine` object

The docs for both can be found here:

- [pandas to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
- [sqlalchemy engine connstr for MSSQL, using pyodbc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc)

As use cases for this can vary greatly from case to case, please refer to the official docs for code examples.